# R if statement comparing strings

Tags: r, string, if-statement, strcmp

I am trying to create a calculated field in R using an if statement that compares strings, which in Excel is easy but I can't figure it out in R. The formula in Excel looks as follows:

```
=IF(AND(E2<>"Accepted", B2=B3,E3="Accepted" ),  -(F2-F3),"")
```

Where Column B is a list of 9-digit numbers (i.e., 200100111), and Column F contains dates. The code I wrote in R is as follows:

`if(df_srt$NUMBER==shift(df_srt$NUMBER, 1L, type="lead") && df_srt$DESCRIPTION != "Accepted" && shift(VA_df_srt$DESCRIPTION, 1L, type="lead")=="Accepted") {1} else {0}`

I then realized that the if statement only compares vector length of 1 so that did not work. I can individually compare strings to get a "TRUE" value as follows:

```
TEST2calc <- df_srt$NUMBER==shift(df_srt$NUMBER, 1L, type="lead")
```

But I want to have those three comparisons and then assign a value if they are all true.

Thanks

Comment: No need for braces around the numbers in your `if`.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, `if` only compares a single value. For a vectorised version, you need to use `ifelse`, and you will likewise need to switch to vectorised versions for `&&` and `||`, which are `&` and `|`, respectively.

Hence:

```
ifelse(df_srt$NUMBER == shift(df_srt$NUMBER, 1L, type = "lead") &
       df_srt$DESCRIPTION != "Accepted" &
       shift(VA_df_srt$DESCRIPTION, 1L, type = "lead") == "Accepted", 1, 0)
```

Alternatively, you can use the fact that logical values can be converted to the numbers 1 and 0 via `as.numeric`:

```
as.numeric(df_srt$NUMBER == shift(df_srt$NUMBER, 1L, type = "lead") &
           df_srt$DESCRIPTION != "Accepted" &
           shift(VA_df_srt$DESCRIPTION, 1L, type = "lead") == "Accepted")
```